# What does Elifecycle error mean?

Tags: node.js, rest, error-handling, server

```
SyntaxError: /Users/DanaCarlin/Desktop/CS612/expensive.json: Unexpected    string in JSON at position 5801
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:654:27)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/DanaCarlin/Desktop/CS612/server.js:2:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! restful-restaurants@0.1.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the restful-restaurants@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely  additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/DanaCarlin/.npm/_logs/2017-12-12T00_22_14_533Z-   debug.log
Danas-MacBook-Air:cs612 DanaCarlin$
```

I don't understand why this keeps popping up!? It was working fine and I've looked through the JSON file and the server.js and can't see anything wrong. I tried to create a docker file from this file so don't know if that is what is making the difference? This is my server.js file

```
server.get('/restaurants', function(request, response){
response.send(JSON.stringify(expensive));
})

server.get('/restaurants:name', function(request, response){
response.send(JSON.stringify(expensive[request.params.name]));
})

server.get('/restaurants:name:/type', function(request, response){
response.send(JSON.stringify(expensive[request.params.name]   [request.params.type]));
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Server listening on port 3000!");
})
```

The JSON file-

```
{
 "WestVillage": {
    "italian" : ["Rafele Restaurante", "LArtusi", "Palma", "Barbuto", "dell'anima", "Morandi", "Via Carota", "I Sodi ","Lupa", "Babbo"],
    "japanese" : ["Takashi","Sushi Nakazawa","Omakase Room by Tatsu", "Saikai", "EN Japanese Brasseri", "Kosaka", "DOMODOMO", "Naoki", "Sushi Samba", "MoriMoto", "catch"],
    "french" : ["Perry St", "Boucherie", "Le Gigot", "Fedora", "The Little Owl","La Ripaille", "La Sirene", "Bagatelle", "BOBO", "Claudette"],
    "american" : ["33 Greenwich", "Market Table", "Chumley's", "The Little OWl", "Coarse NYC", "Employees Only", "Wallflower", "Hudson Clearwater", "Bespolke Kitchen", "Quality Eats"],
    "chinese" : ["Decoy", "RedFarm", "Buddakan", "Pinch Chinese", "Jue Lan Club", "Tao Downtown"],
    "spanish" : ["Tertulia", "Alta", "Salinas", "Socarrat Paella Bar", "Boqueria" ,"Toro"],
    "cafe" : ["Unlimited Possibilities", "Saint Ambreus West village", "Abington Market", "Satrudays Surf NYC", "MarieBelle", "Society Cafe", "Ralpha-new York", "Village 122", "MerriWeather"],
    "thai" : ["RedFarm", "Mr. Jones Supper Club"],
    "indian" : ["Rahi", "Paowalla"],
    "vietnamese" : [],
    "greek" : ["Bar Bolonat", "Casa La Femme", "Fig & Olive","Alta"]
},

"Flatiron" : {
    "italian" : ["Maialino", "Marta", "Giorgios of Gramercy", "Zio Ristorante", " Manzo Ristorante", "Obica Mozzarella Bar Pizza e Cucina", "Osteria del Principe", "fusco", "Italienne", "Novita Restaurant", "Paul& JImmy's", "Mamma Guidara's", "I Trulli", "Trattoria Il Mulino", "Bocca Restaurant & Bar", "Asselina", "Cipriani 23rd st", "A Voce"],
    "japanese" : ["O Ya", "TEISUI", "Yakiniky Futago", "Roki Le IZakaya", "15 East Restaurant", "SUGARFISH by sushi nozawa", "Hillstone", "Blue Water Grill", "Hanjan"],
    "french" : ["ABC kitchen", "The NoMad restaurant", "Bouley Test Kitchen", "Eleven Madison Park", "Italliene", "Tocqueville Restuarant", "Le Coq Rico", "Le Restaurant d'Alex", "Boqueria"],
    "vietnamese" : ["The Pho", "BONMI","Num Pang Kitchen", "Luu's Baguette","Jimmy's House", "Saigon Market", "Republic", "Noodles 28"],
    "american" : ["Covina", "Gramercy Tavern", "Upland", "ABC kitchen", "The Gander", "Black Barn", "Union Square Cafe", "Maysville", "Hillstone", "Irvington"],
    "chinese" : ["Jue Lan Club", "Atoboy"],
    "spanish" : ["Sala One Nine", "Boqueria", "Casa Mono", "Aldea", "ABC Cocina", "Latin American Restaurant", "Raymi", "Latin Beef Kitchen", "Sophie's Cuban Cuisine", "Bar Jamon"],
    "cafe" : ["Covina", "Union Square Cafe", "Van Leeuwen Coffee Truck", "Society Cafe", "Blank Slate"],
    "thai" : ["ABCV", "Atoboy", "Thai Vila", "Jue Lan Club"],
    "greek" : ["Periyali", "Ilili", "Almayass Restaurant NYC", "Barbounia", "Zio Restorante"],
    "indian" : ["Junoon", "ABCV", "Babu Ji"]
},

"Tribeca" : {
    "italian" : ["Pepolino Restaurant", "Locanda Verde", "Scalini Fedeli", "Gran Morsi", "Ecco", "Tutto il Giorno", "The Odeon", "Mamo Restaurant", "Petrarca Cucina E Vino", "Osteria Morini"],
    "japanese" : ["Shigure", "Sushi Azabu", "Ichimura", "Brushstroke", "Takahachi Tribeca Restaurant", "Ninja New York", "DOMODOMO", "Sushi of Gari", "Hirohisa", "Blue Ribbon"],
    "french" : ["Bouley", "Batard", "Racines", "The Odeon", "MAMO Restaurant", "La Sirene", "Le Coucou", "Balthazar", "Taureau", "LAppart"],
    "american" : ["American Cut Steakhouse","City Vineyard", "Marc Forgione", "The Bennett", "Little Park", "The Odeon", "Yves", "Tribeca Grill", "Atera", "Batard", "Brandy Library"],
    "chinese" : ["Mr. Chow", "Macao", "KheYo"],
    "spanish" : ["Tablao", "Sazon", "Despana", "Estancia 460", "Westside Coffee Shop", "Anejo Tribeca", "Terra Wine Bar", "Darlene", "Sophia's Cuban Cuisine", "Amada"],
    "cafe" : ["Arcade Bakery", "Galerie de Cafe", "The Wooly Daily", "Cafe Belle", "Baked", "Laughing Man Coffee and Tea","La Colombe Coffee", "Kuro-Obi at Canal Street Market", "Blue Spoon Coffee", "Everyman Espresso"],
    "thai" : ["kheyo", "Empire", "Macao"],
    "indian" : ["Tamarind"],
    "vietnamese" : [],
    "greek" : []
},

"Chelsea" : {
    "italian" : ["Pepolino Restaurant", "Locanda Verde", "Scalini Fedeli", "Gran Morsi", "Ecco", "Tutto il Giorno", "The Odeon", "Mamo Restaurant", "Petrarca Cucina E Vino", "Osteria Morini"],
    "japanese" : ["Shigure", "Sushi Azabu", "Ichimura", "Brushstroke", "Takahachi Tribeca Restaurant", "Ninja New York", "DOMODOMO", "Sushi of Gari", "Hirohisa", "Blue Ribbon"],
    "french" : ["Bouley", "Batard", "Racines", "The Odeon", "MAMO Restaurant", "La Sirene", "Le Coucou", "Balthazar", "Taureau", "L'Appart"],
    "american" : ["American Cut Steakhouse","City Vineyard", "Marc Forgione", "The Bennett", "Little Park", "The Odeon", "Yves", "Tribeca Grill", "Atera", "Batard", "Brandy Library"],
    "chinese" : ["Mr. Chow", "Macao", "Khe-Yo"],
    "spanish" : ["Tablao", "Sazon", "Despana", "Estancia 460", "Westside Coffee Shop", "Anejo Tribeca", "Terra Wine Bar", "Darlene", "Sophia's Cuban Cuisine", "Amada"],
    "thai" : ["Blossom", "Buddakan"],
    "indian" : ["Aroqa", "Blossom"],
    "vietnamese" : [],
    "greek" : ["Death Ave", "Mykonos Blue", "Papa Kabab Meditteranean Bistro", "The Hummus and Pita", "Wrapido", "Lemony", "Stix Bar and Grill", "Periyali"],
    "cafe" : ["Middle Eats", "Van Leeuwen Coffee Truck"]
},

"Tribeca" : {
    "italian" : ["Del Posto", "Mulino a Vino", "Scarpetta", "Da Umberto", "La Sirena Ristorante", "Cassa Nona", "Crispo", "Il Bastardo"],
    "japanese" : ["Ushiwakamaru", "Juban", "Naoki", "Morimoto", "Momoya", "Megu", "Kappo Totto", "Sushi Seki-Chelsea"],
    "french" : ["Mykonos Blue", "periyali", "La Piscine"],
    "american" : ["The CLub Car at the McKittrick Hotel", "The Red Cat", "Gallow Green", "Rouge Tomate Chelsea", "The Heath", "Motel Morris", "Tipsy Parson", "33 Greenwich", "Kola House", "Fred's Downtown"],
    "chinese" : ["Buddakan", "Jue Lan Club", "Tao Downtown""Ushiwakamaru", "Juban", "Naoki", "Morimoto", "Momoya", "Megu", "Kappo Totto", "Sushi Seki-Chelsea"],
    "spanish" : ["Salinas", "Soccarat Paella Bar", "Tia Pol", "El Quijote", "Toro", "Francisco's Centro Vasco","Txikito", "Boqueria", "La Sirena istorante", "Lupulo"],
    "cafe" : ["Arcade Bakery", "Galerie de Cafe", "The Wooly Daily", "Cafe Belle", "Baked", "Laughing Man Coffee and Tea","La Colombe Coffee", "Kuro-Obi at Canal Street Market", "Blue Spoon Coffee", "Everyman Espresso"],
    "thai" : ["khe-yo", "Empire", "Macao"],
    "indian" : ["Tamarind"],
    "vietnamese" : ["Khe-Yo", "Macao"],
    "greek" : ["The Greek", "Thalassa", "Antique Garage Tribeca"]
}
```

}

There must be something in here that is wrong but I can't find it anywhere!!

Comment: server.js codevar express = require('express');
var expensive = require('./expensive.json');
var server = express();

//server.get('/', function(request, response){
  //response.sendFile("index.html");
//})

Comment: server.get('/restaurants', function(request, response){
  response.send(JSON.stringify(expensive));
})

server.get('/restaurants:name', function(request, response){
  response.send(JSON.stringify(expensive[request.params.name]));
})

server.get('/restaurants:name:/type', function(request, response){
  response.send(JSON.stringify(expensive[request.params.name][request.params.type]));
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000!");
})

Comment: put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is malformed, with an unexpected character in it. The error is in the parsing of that bad JSON. Put a try..catch block around it and work to debug the formatting of the input. If you can post the JSON you're trying to parse we can get more details to you.

Comment: I added the JSON file